# Creating a meteorite by throwing a stone

Tags: internal-consistency, meteor, astronaut

Bob is an astronaut. He is in love with Alice. For his next EVA in a LEO mission, Bob knows that he will be flying above Alice's farm, located in an area without light pollution, during a moonless night.

He thinks that he can be able to send her a romantic gesture, and ask her to look up in the sky around the time he will be passing by.

He carries with him 3 cobblestones, about the size of a tennis ball. He wraps them in copper wires (leftover from some do-it-yourself electricity work in his garage) and ask his captain to inform him via the intercom when they will be flying above the coordinates of the farm.

His plan is to simply hand launch the stones toward Earth and then hopefully Alice will see 3 greenish shooting stars in her sky.

Can this plan achieve the hoped result?

*Edit: As also pointed out in some of the answers, a real astronaut on a real spaceship would not jeopardize him/herself and the mission by carrying extra weight and throwing out some "garbage" for personal reason. However fictional worlds have different rules (else we would not ask if Star Wars fighter can PEW PEW when firing). In this fictional world the astronaut managed to carry something and to throw it, and thanks to some of the answers I can already correct the "target" to something smaller than cobblestones and maybe lighter, like a golf ball*

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment since answers stating the same in a much better way exist, but I want to bring to your attention that smuggling those objects into space and then scheduling a spacewalk (I'm assuming something like that?) for some shenanigans doesn't sound like something that would actually happen. Also note that those walks are incredibly tedious and dangerous.

Comment: As usual, I strongly advise playing Kerbal Space Program to get a grasp on the orbital mechanics. Burning in the direction of the planet is wasteful idea. Retrograde burn gives most deorbit from given delta V.

Comment: You need 2 things: your cobblestones and let it falls within the meteoric zone(80 to 120km above sea level), don't be too concern with its speed if you're dropping it from orbit.

Comment: @user6760, as your comment seems to go against all other answers so far, I'd gladly see it expanded as a proper answer

Comment: I have amended my answer since I realized that if we just scale the size requirement down a bit, then it is possible. And since anything larger than a grain of sand will be visible from Earth, we have plenty of room to scale back.

Comment: How is this world building? Shouldn't it be voted for closure? At the least, it should be on the Physics sight, not this one. Or is there one rule for the residents, and one for the rest of us?

Comment: @Mołot retrograde burns give the cheapest re-entry in terms of delta-v, but will it be the fastest way in terms of time-to-start-shining?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## If he makes a giant potato-gun / slingshot / mini-rocket. Or(!)...

Our good old friend [Sir Isaac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton) is a right honorable <strike>jerk</strike> **troublesome fellow** in these circumstances. According to [his first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), in order to de-orbit something, you need to **decrease your speed in orbit** <sub>(*)</sub>. [You need a change (normally denominated *delta*, $\Delta$) of velocity ($v$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) of at least 150 m/s to de-orbit from Low Earth Orbit.

Space suits are bulky cumbersome things. You simply cannot perform anything with the speed and agility you normally do. And even without that hindrance [a really good baseball pitcher can get no better than 50 m/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aroldis_Chapman) out of a good pitch.

So in order to achieve a delta-v of 150 m/s, Astronaut Bob will need to "cheat"

At first I thought that a slingshot might do it, but the draw length available, combined with the force needed to achieve 150 m/s for a tennis balls-sized object is somewhat prohibitive. He will not be able to pull that back by hand. A winch with a quick-release might do the trick.

Another way to do it might be to bring a big [potato cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_cannon).

Or he might be able to bring a little hobby rocket to attach to the stones.

## However...

All of these things are **dangerous to the space craft**. And they add weight to the launch. Weight is a precious commodity on space launches.

And since Astronaut Bob — albeit a very romantic guy — is also a scientist/engineer, and a sensible such (because hotshots do not get to become astronauts), he will not try to sneak this aboard. He will think up another way of displaying his affection to his beloved Alice.

## ...or: he can use something smaller. (Late edit)

If Astronaut Bob settles for **smaller projectiles** — say marble-sized copper balls, instead of the tennis ball-sized you first specified — then he might be on to something. [A handheld slingshot can achieve a "muzzle" velocity of up to 500 ft per second](http://www.theslingshotforum.com/threads/what-is-the-maximum-velocity-possible.27391/). That is right on the mark: 150 m/s. And since [objects as small as a grain of sand will make a "shooting star" that is visible to the naked eye](http://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/1999/01/how-big-are-the-meteors-that-we-see-as-shooting-stars-what-factors-affect-their-color-length-and-intensity), a ball between 1 to 3 cm in diameter will make a very good visible meteorite.

Drawing example from the fact that [astronauts have smuggled aboard "contraband" before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_Astronaut), something as small as a few copper balls and a slingshot does fit within the wiggle room they have for weight; the tolerances will allow it.

Also, if Astronaut Bob is really good friends with his fellow crew-mates... they can help provide the conditions for him to do this — highly unauthorized — very romantic gesture and get away with it.

From this, all Astronaut Bob needs is a ton of good luck, because margins are narrow to say the least. But you are the author... you decide if he succeeds. With a slingshot and smaller projectiles, **yes, then it is physically possible for Astronaut Bob to make a shooting star for his beloved Alice**.

[image]

*The 'Fallen Astronaut', placed on the Moon by the Apollo 15 crew, was **not** sanctioned by NASA*

<sub>(*) Being in orbit is like falling towards the planet; you are in constant free-fall. But since you have such a high **sideways** speed, what happens is that you keep missing the Earth. So in order to come down from space, you do not throw yourself in the direction of the Earth, because that will fail. What you do to come back to the surface is that you **slow down** (i.e. you "throw" yourself **backwards**. Once you have slowed down enough, your free-fall will then bring you into the atmosphere. From there, the atmosphere will slow you down more, and your return to Earth is guaranteed (almost).</sub>

Comment: I'd need a better reference than that to believe that a grain of sand would cause a visible shooting star.  Maybe if it was going _very_ fast, but I doubt a small rock falling off a orbiting craft is going to be visible.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It has nothing to do with **size** but the **amount of light** it emits.

Comment: NOTHING in low earth orbit will orbit forever. EVERYTHING will eventually 'fall'. The only question is, how SOON will it fall. Changing it by 150 m/s night be the difference between hundreds of years and a few months, but certainly not reduce the time to a few minutes.

Comment: @JustinThyme According to you and what orbital engineer?

Comment: @MichaelK [Lost in Space: 8 Weird Pieces of Space Junk](https://www.wired.com/2009/02/spacestuff/) Does NASA count as an expert? I believe they have a few orbital engineers on staff.

Comment: @JustinThyme They would, if that article had supported your claim that a delta-v of 150 m/s is not enough to deorbit something from Low Earth Orbit. But it does not. I am sorry but "Here is a link that mentions NASA, therefore I am right" does not a proper argument make.

Comment: @MichaelK 'From tiny bolts to whole space stations, people have discarded lots of stuff up there. Much of it eventually dies a fiery death as it falls through Earth’s atmosphere, but some larger debris poses risks for astronauts and spacecraft that could collide with it. ' Everything eventually falls. Unless it hits something else, and THEN falls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68890/discussion-between-michaelk-and-justin-thyme).

Comment: Possibly a sling is a better launcher than a slingshot. Slingshots designed for Earth performance probably fair poorly in space, but a sling requires little more than a length of wire and room to swing.

Comment: Don't forget that any force in space has an opposite reaction. Something with a lot of kick could actually shoot the astronaut quite far off course, so make sure he is tethered or has the ability to re-adjust.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt **Really** bad idea. A sling is difficult as it is to control properly. In a space suit(!)... no way. Also, what is to say the slingshot cannot work in space?!

Comment: @PhilM A 0.1 kg projectile vs a 100+ kg astronaut & suit... means that a delta-v of 150 m/s on the projectile means an opposing velocity on the astronaut of... 0.15 m/s. Not exactly "a lot of kick".

Comment: @MichaelK I don't know that a slingshot won't work, but I know temperature cycling and sun exposure wares rubber so I guess space would be hard on it. If the characteristics of whatever material is used to make the slingshot changes significantly it would likely be less good. I do see how a sling has some serious difficulties in control and safety, but the properties that make it work are going to be effected by space.

Comment: @MichaelK I was referring to the kick of the potato gun which is usually just a rapid release of compressed air (and less about the mass of the potato). It might be the equivalent of a 5 sec burn from the spacesuit navigation unit, but that isn't necessarily trival.

Comment: [Alan Shepard's golf club](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/february/6/newsid_4093000/4093061.stm) is perhaps a more famous example of Apollo contraband.

Comment: @JPhi1618, How about a grain of sand hitting the atmosphere at 45,000 miles per hour?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I do not understand your comment. Why would Bob leave the slingshot out in space before using it? No, that makes no sense. Instead he would put it in his tool-bag, so that it is inside the spacecraft with him until it is time for his EVA.

Comment: Orbital velocity is one third of that - 15,000 mph. A significant difference. At that speed, a cobblestone might not even melt.

Comment: @David Richerby hey, maybe Bob should play golf in space, huh? Tee off a solar panel, maybe. But if you yell "Fore" in space, who hears you?

Comment: @JustinThyme Just stop it. You are not trying to help, you are just trying to shoot down the concept. As tragic as it was, if you watch footage from Space Shuttle Columbia disaster, you can easily see a myriad of parts come off of it, parts that glow and that you can follow with the naked eye. Peak temperatures on the leading edges during a space shuttle de-orbit reached over 2000 degrees C. So just give it up... I do not know why you have put it into your head to be querulous about this, but you are not being very nice here.

Comment: @MichaelK  The debris trail from the Columbia disaster was from the vapor trail. The same trail given off by jets. I don't recall the Columbia glowing like a meteor before it broke up, just a vapor trail. I believe all I have done is presented the evidence. But, yes, one could say that the defense presenting evidence that shoots down the prosecution evidence is not very nice - to the prosecution. The defense just isn't very helpful to the prosecution.

Answer (score 33):

Baseball pitchers can throw a ball at around [100mph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastball).

That's really quite impressive, however they train to do this and they have good footing. They're also not throwing the ball very far.

Bob is in orbit, he's throwing the ball with a starting speed of about [15,000mph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed) perpendicular to the direction he wants it to go, and being generous, 100mph in the intended direction of travel.

*He's only a few hundred miles up, doesn't that mean the rock will eventually hit the atmosphere to make his shooting star?*

The Earth is only 7915 miles across, given an hour to be 100miles closer, and taking his 15,000mph orbital speed into consideration, he's going to miss the planet completely and now his rock is travelling at 100mph away from the Earth. His shooting star is now in a different, [slightly more eccentric orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12011/how-could-a-90-m-s-delta-v-be-enough-to-commit-the-space-shuttle-to-landing/12014#12014) than the one Bob himself is in.

That orbit may eventually decay and create the shooting star somewhere as Bob intended, or it may interact destructively with Bob's own orbit, much to the dismay of his captain.

In short, throwing his rock directly towards Earth, he could put his rocks into another orbit, but he's not able to throw them hard enough to overcome orbital speed.

Comment: See [this answer on sister stack](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12014/11639), to wonderful [How could a 90 m/s delta-v be enough to commit the space shuttle to landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12011/11639) question. Turns out **it can**. Not to directly hit the ground, but to interact with atmosphere, and that's what we need here, too. 100 mph = 45 m/s **is half way there**.

Comment: @Mołot Ah now that's a different calculation that MichaelK has gone into, calculating it as delta-v would require you to fire it backwards along the orbital path. Firing it perpendicular to the path as asked gives a much more complex solution which destabilises the orbit rather than necessarily causing reentry.

Comment: I guess OP was more interested in getting this done than in getting this done by exact direction of the throw. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @Mołot, he does say `simply hand launch the stones towards Earth` it's important to note explicitly that this wouldn't work, but since MichaelK has posted about the delta-v I didn't feel it necessary to go into what would work.

Comment: @Mołot, I'm stealing that link to indicate the new orbit of his rocks though :)

Comment: Assuming Bob is _close_ to the atmosphere, what he can do is throw the rock **retrograde** (not at the planet, but "backwards" given his current velocity vector) when he is at the **opposite** side of the planet. This would give him the most bang for his buck in terms of lowering the rock's periapsis enough that it grazes the atmosphere (while Bob doesn't).

Comment: @Flater: Basically correct, but Bob would also have to do the throw several thousand miles before he's above Alice's farm, and at a precisely-calculated velocity.  And as others note, I don't think an unaided human could throw that hard, or that precisely.

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume that Bob is in an orbit similar to those that the Space Shuttle was normally operating in.

In such an orbit, a [200 ft/s retrograde burn](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12011/415) was in some circumstances sufficient to deorbit the Shuttle. Depending on the specific orbit, the required delta-v could be as large as 550 ft/s. In civilized units, this corresponds to 61-168 m/s. The rest of the Shuttle's velocity was shedded via atmospheric drag.

MichaelK (who is not me, I promise!) has already [mentioned](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/98121/29) that [a good baseball pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aroldis_Chapman) can pitch 50 m/s.

Sure, as already discussed, it's hard to be a great baseball pitcher when you're wearing a spacesuit. But maybe we can handwave this away by saying that at some indeterminate point in the future, astronaut protective gear has advanced sufficiently to allow something much like that.

We can probably assume that Bob is able to use the spacecraft to prevent himself from being thrown in the other direction. (Bonus: If his tether breaks, and he's carrying these stones, he can just throw one in the direction away from the spacecraft to head back to the spacecraft. See, *it's a safety system, and he's testing to see how well it works!* It's official mission business!)

**The difference between 50 m/s and 61 m/s is sufficiently small that this borders on plausibility. It would be hard, but perhaps not impossible.**

Now, the *direction* he'd have to throw the stone in is counterintuitive. Throwing it downwards (technically, toward nadir) won't work. I'm fairly certain that he'd want to throw it directly *retrograde*, back the way he came from, possibly at a very slight angle, but Bob would need to discuss the specifics with his flight dynamics officer to be certain.

Also, unless Bob is already in the appreciable atmosphere, the right time to make the throw isn't when he's over Alice's farm, but rather, *roughly* on the other side of the planet. But this can be calculated relatively accurately, so is not really a problem. Again, talk to the FDO.

So, if Bob's superiors are in on the idea, and he is able to throw the stone in just the right direction at just the right time, with a speed relative to himself (and the spacecraft, hopefully) just slightly higher than that of a good baseball pitch (which places requirement on Bob's protective gear which are not currently met), then **he *might* be able to pull this off.**

Unfortunately, the odds that Bob's superiors would be in on the idea are pretty slim, given that this would incur a fair mass penalty on the spacecraft. **So he probably won't get a chance to try it.** Consequently, as already discussed, Bob, being a practical man, will probably think of some other way to display his affection to Alice.

But it's a nice thought, and it's the thought that counts, isn't it?

Comment: I was torn if I should post [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98112/creating-a-meteorite-by-throwing-a-stone/98125#comment291622_98117) as comment or answer... Turns out, it should've been an answer.

Comment: @Mołot Notice who posted that question on SXSE.

Comment: I know, I know.

Comment: Just releasing the orbs from the spacecraft will cause them to eventually fall to earth. Nothing in LEO will stay in orbit forever. The only question is, how SOON will they come back to earth? It might just be months, if they are simply let go, it might be years, but it will never be minutes.  Chances are, he will be back on earth before they land. And, if they are granite cobblestones, they will most certainly survive to land.

Comment: @JustinThyme Actually, "how soon will they come back to Earth?" is one relevant question. The other is "where will they pass through the atmosphere and ultimately collide with the ground?".

Comment: @Michael Kjörling♦ If the OP wants it to land within a reasonable time (a few minutes, say, so she is not outside for weeks, and he wants it to be directly above her house, then he would have to completely cancel the orbital velocity so that it drops straight down. Canceling 15,000 m/hr would be some pitching arm. Especially since it would have to be done almost instantaneously, otherwise he misses the mark. He would have quite a career in  baseball ahead of him if he could do it. Now, a laser beam on the clouds would be a neat trick.

Comment: @JustinThyme It's perfectly possible to calculate a reentry retro burn (throw) impulse that would cause reentry into the appreciable atmosphere at a fairly well-known location. If we're talking about cancelling out orbital velocity entirely Bob might just as well throw it straight down; would probably take less impulse, and give the same result in that case. I tried to stay at least within the realm of reasonable, though. :-)

Comment: @Michael Kjörling♦ In fact, the software tool I referenced in my answer will give a good approximation to the time and place, if one so chooses to download it, learn it,and then enter in the right parameters. NASA created it just for this purpose, among others. Debris Assessment Software User’s Guide Version 2.1

Comment: Mechanical Counter Pressure (MCP) space suits are starting to become mainstream research. They fit like a diver's dry suit that's about 2 sizes too small. A good throw is manageable If the astronaut can anchor his feet well. You might consider a sling (as in David and Goliath). Delta V of 59m/s was measured in research cited in this link (http://slinging.org/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1215377301/15). Knowing that shot from slings can break bone, 65 m/s is readily achievable.

Comment: @pojo-guy Also any mechanical solution needs to survive the absolute zero of space. Can you really imaging slingshots still having the durability and flexibility required to work at those temperatures?

Comment: @PhilM Not a slingshot - a sling.  Two pieces of string and a pouch to hold the shot. The cotton canvas exterior of the LB7 did reasonably well for surviving the cold of space (better than the synthetics). The sling only needs to last for a couple of uses. Two shoe strings and a tongue from an old shoe should do the trick.

Comment: Actually, he wants to throw a bit more than half an orbit before he passes over the farm.  They will reach their lowest point half an orbit after being thrown but that isn't the point of maximum brilliance.  Drag will slow them and take them deeper into the atmosphere where you will get much more heating.  The additional distance needed depends on the mass and drag of the objects thrown, there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer and calculating it is far beyond my ability anyway.

Comment: From my experience with KSP the distance might be considerable.  Also, I don't think a human has a chance of getting it right, playing at the fringes of the atmosphere is so sensitive.

Comment: @pojo-guy Yes, that's something like what I had in mind.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Indeed, which is why I recommended discussing it with the FDO. After all, it's their *job* to get that sort of things just right.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No--I'm saying that even if you know the exact numbers human accuracy simply isn't good enough to ensure it burns in where you intend.

Answer (score 7):

[image: How to deploy a meteorite]

In order for Bob's cobblestones to be visible above Alice's house, he's going to need to brush up on orbital decay, drag and gravity. Or crib off the work of ALE’s “Sky Canvas” project, which I am sort of doing right now.

ALE would like to release colored meteorites into the atmosphere for a show. As you can see by the handy info-graphic, some planning has to happen to use gravity, friction, drag into account for proper deployment.

Bob is in orbit moving around 15,000 mph. In order for his cobblestones to hit the sky above Alice's house, he's going to have to figure a way to de-orbit them, or slow them down so they drop exactly(ish) where he wants them. If he releases them and lets them fend for themselves, it could take several years before their orbit decays enough to fall to earth.

For a more precise entry, he's going to need a device like a rocket to slow down the cobblestones for a more precise de-orbit. This means during his EVA, he may have to start the de-orbiting process hours or days in advance of being over Alice's house. The exact timing depends on how fast Bob wants to de-orbit them.

If I could make a suggestion, it would be to use strontium and magnesium instead of plain old cobblestones. The strontium will burn bright red and illuminate the sky. The magnesium will create a whitish blue that will be extremely visible.

- https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/06/artificial-meteor-showers-japan-satellite-space-science/
- http://www.bbc.com/news/av/technology-37928806/shooting-stars-from-space-for-2020-olympics

Good luck.

[image: Colored meteorites]

Comment: If Bob is a professional astronaut, I should hope those matters are not something he'll need to _brush up on_.

Comment: @Henning Makholm If Bob is a professional astronaut, he wouldn't even be considering this. It would be the end of his career.

Comment: @JustinThyme, - Oh the things men do for a pretty face like Alice.

Answer (score 6):

Orbit isn't far away.  Orbit is closer than a nearby city.  Orbit is [*fast away*](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/).

Things in orbit are going at a ridiculous speed so that they [*miss* the Earth](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Flying) in the time it would take them to fall to the ground, and instead end up on the other side.

The small amount of impulse a throwing arm could give would result in a slightly different orbit, missing the Earth differently, unless the orbit was already extremely low.

If the orbit was extremely low, then an impulse could result in the stones being slowed down slightly more by the atmosphere.  This would reduce its orbit even more, and eventually it would fall to the planet.  Of course, the same was true of the original "orbit", it would just happen faster here.

Accuracy would be next to impossible, as the tumble and air resistance properties of the stone would be difficult to predict, and the rentry point would be sensitive to relatively small changes in the speed and direction the rocks where thrown at.  The stone could easily take more than one orbit to fall, with the shape of second (and later) orbits a function of how much speed it bled off in the earlier close approaches.

It would definitely not involve throwing the stones "at" the location in question.

Answer (score 1):

No, because he is moving far too fast for the rock to either slow down enough to freefall or travel far enough to reach the thicker atmosphere where it will burn up before it has traveled too far to long to be seen by his love. He could throw it toward earth LONG before he is above her, so the rock has enough time to reach the atmosphere above her.But even then i think it would miss the earth(though i don't know)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Would you be able to explain your reasoning here? Especially the bit where you talk about missing the Earth, which is quite big and tends to attract things (especially small ones) towards it... Also, do you *know* it'll burn up when thrown from a LEO orbit?

Comment: I don't know if you knew this, but the fact that the bob is ORBITING means that he is falling towards earth but then missing it.  If he threw the rock it would probably end up in a more eratic orbit, but since he is moving so fast it doesn't matter that the earth is attracting the rock and it doesn't matter that the earth is huge the rock would still miss.

Comment: That's true in an *ideal* scenario, but in Low Earth Orbit (LEO), objects tend to experience atmospheric drag to a large enough extent that the object will slow down and spiral in towards the Earth. That is, it may very well burn up in the atmosphere, but it won't *miss* the Earth

Comment: ... The point is that the scenario isn't ideal and so the object will de-orbit *by itself*. For future notice, it might be worth thinking about how *guessing* an answer makes it a good answer and how constructive statements like "Be gone." are for getting good answers

Comment: Mithrandir you have simply been provoking me, and i did not apreciate it. THat is why i wanted you to leave me alone.

Comment: The reason that i answered the question even though i was not sure of the math, was because there was no other answer at the time.

Comment: @Georgios Nothing Mithrandir wrote appears to be provocation.  There are certain expectations for what constitutes a proper answer on the site and from what I am reading he is simply trying to guide you.  Check out the [tour] and [help] to get an idea of what he is trying to share.  Mithrandir, try to explain what you are doing when you are working with new users.  Be Nice all. :D

Answer (score -2):

There is just so much that is wrong about this.

First, he is an astronaut. He would have taken extensive courses in orbital dynamics. He would understand the math and the physics. There would be no speculation. He would KNOW.

Second, the orbs would already have a forward velocity. Dropping them does not destroy it. Should he drop them over his sweetheart's house they would continue their forward velocity, and certainly not enter atmosphere above her house. Perhaps they might re-enter in a few years or so. [Lost in Space: 8 Weird Pieces of Space Junk](https://www.wired.com/2009/02/spacestuff/) He would not need to sway her into going outside when he released them. He could wait until he got back home and was with her. They could watch it together. Somewhere. But probably not over her house.

Third, meteors 'burn up' because of the tremendous speed (roughly 20 km./sec.) at which they they hit the earth. The slower speed of these orbs (approx. 6 km./sec.) would not produce nearly the fireworks. The copper wire would be naught but fluff floating in the wind. It may glow, but certainly no naked eyesight observable effects. And it would never stay wrapped around the orb. The cobblestones would probably get hot enough to cause the surrounding air to glow, and one might get enough light from them to be seen by a good telescope that was aimed directly at them. Cobblestone balls, however, because of their high melting point and round shape, are more likely to actually survive and hit ground then burn up. [SPACECRAFT REENTRY](http://www.aerospace.org/cords/all-about-debris-and-reentry/spacecraft-reentry/) There is a greater chance of his love being hit by the orbs than of her seeing them.

Fourth, it is strictly against regulations, and would not be tolerated. Doing so would get the astronaut evicted from the space program. Debris release from spacecraft is strictly regulated. Given that it WOULD be tracked, there is no possible way it could be covered up.

See the following guidelines [Debris Assessment Software User’s Guide Version 2.1](https://www.orbitaldebris.jsc.nasa.gov/library/das2_1_1/das2.1_usersguide.pdf) if you are at all interested in a NASA software tool for calculating the orbits and time frame for debris in LEO, as well as regulations regarding space debris.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your answer: 1) Yes, Bob would know. OP does not know, and is trying to figure out. 2) Bob would — of course — **throw** (that is what OP said, not "drop") at the appropriate window in space and time. 3a) Nothing in that article say that the orbital speed of something in LEO is not enough to make it glow. 3b) The object can be **modified** to better suit Bob's needs. Nothing says it must be that which OP suggested and absolutely nothing else. 4) Yes, it is a stunt. However since this is **fiction** we can allow Bob to get away with it, either by stealth or leniency.

Comment: Down-vote because you are more focused on shooting down the concept than trying to find a solution, and for bringing forth unnecessary and querulous points into the post in order to achieve this.

Comment: @MichaelK The OP question was 'Can this plan achieve the hoped result?' My answer is, for good and sound reasons, 'No, it can not'. It is neither realistic nor feasible. It is neither scientifically valid nor logistically valid. Just because you do not like the implications of the answer, does not make it a bad one.

Comment: Maintaining my down-vote because "No, that exact plan cannot work" is a bad answer while "It could work, if you make the following reasonable changes" is a much better one. You even go as far to stick the strikt meaning of individual **words** ("drop" instead of "throw") just to be able to shoot down the answer.

Comment: @MichaelK There are no reasonable changes that could be made to the OP proposal that could make it work. Magic and handwaving are the only alternatives. It falls into the category of a perpetual motion machine. It totally defies physics, reality, evidence, and orbital mechanics. Further, it is totally dangerous and jeopardizes the entire mission. Making a meteor by throwing a stone is, simply, a non-starter.

Comment: You apparently did not read any other answers in this thread.

Comment: @MichaelK floccinaucinihilipilification

Comment: Just a reminder all.  Be nice.